# Calculate bowling score recursively

Tags: java, recursion

Just for practice, I am trying to solve the bowling problem in java recursively, I've already solved the problem but in non-recursive solution but I feel that the scoring part suits recursion so much. Below is my trial that I am sure it is not near to correct, but this is how I thought about the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Bowling
{

int [] game;
Scanner s ;

public Bowling() 
{
    s= new Scanner (System.in);
    game = new int[21];

}

public void playGame()
{
    int pins = 0;
    String input ="";
    boolean strickOrSpare =false;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) 
    {
        strickOrSpare =false;
        System.out.println("You are in frame "+(i+1)+ "in the first throw, please enter the number of pins");
        input = s.nextLine();
        pins = Integer.parseInt(input);     
        game[i*2] = pins;

        while( (pins > 10) || (pins <0))
        {
            System.out.println("You entered invalid number, please enter the number of pins for first throw");
            input = s.nextLine();
            pins = Integer.parseInt(input);             
            game[i*2] = pins;
        }

        if( pins == 10)
        {
            System.out.println("A Strik!");
            strickOrSpare =true;
            if (i != 9)
                continue;
        }

        //////////////////////////////////////////////second throw////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        System.out.println("Please enter the number of pins for second throw");
        input = s.nextLine();
        pins = Integer.parseInt(input);
        game[(i*2)+1] = pins;

        while(( (game[i*2] + game[(i*2)+1] > 10) || (game[i*2]+ game[(i*2)+1] < 0)) && i!=9)
        {
            System.out.println("You entered invalid number, please enter the number of pins for second throw");
            input = s.nextLine();
            pins = Integer.parseInt(input);             
            game[(i*2)+1] = pins;
        }

        if( game[i*2] + game[(i*2)+1]  == 10)
        {
            strickOrSpare =true;
            System.out.println("A Spare!");
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////Last Frame case//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        if(i == 9)
        {       
            if( strickOrSpare )
            {
                System.out.println("Please enter the number of pins for third throw");
                input = s.nextLine();
                pins = Integer.parseInt(input);
                game[(i*2)+2] = pins;
            }
        }
    }
}

public int calculateScore()
{
    return helperCalculateScore(0, 0);
}

private int helperCalculateScore(int index, int scoreSoFar)
{
    if( index == 18)
    {
        if ( game[index] ==10)
            scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ 10 + game[19] + game[20];
        else if ( game[index] + game[index+1 ]==10)
            scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ 10 + game[20];
        else 
            scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ game[18] + game[19];
    } 
    else if( (index%2 == 0) && (game[index]==10)) //strik
    {
        scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ 10 + helperCalculateScore (index+1, scoreSoFar) + helperCalculateScore (index+2, scoreSoFar);
    }
    else if( (index%2 == 1) && (game[index] + game[index-1] ==10)) //spare
    {
        scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ 10 + helperCalculateScore (index+1, scoreSoFar);
    }
    else
    {
        scoreSoFar = scoreSoFar+ game[index];
        helperCalculateScore (index+1, scoreSoFar);
    }

    return scoreSoFar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Bowling b = new Bowling();
    b.playGame();
System.out.println(b.calculateScore());

}

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The best solution to this question would be to add to the score as the game is being played. You would have to make sure though that after a strike or spare the score gets doubled for the next 2/1 frames. And a tiny bit more logic for the 10th frame.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use recursion in the block that calculates strikes or spares, instead just add on the values from the next 2 or 1 frames respectively. After that you can make a recursive call on `index+2` or `index+1` respectively. Make sure that any time you make a recursive call, you are incrementing the score by what it returns. You forgot that in your `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my job interviews I was asked to implement a `ScoringBowling` calculator. you can find my solution on GitHub: https://github.com/othmankurdi/ScoringBowling

I know it's too late now, but might be helpful for others :)